# How to convert an image file to BMP programmatically using native Windows XP capabilities?

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, wsh, image-conversion, jscript

Is it possible to convert an image file to BMP format using WindowsXP's native libraries and scripting capabilities?

I'm talking about WSH, JScript, VBS, etc...
C++ is also good for what I need if it can be compiled with Dev-C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462%28VS.85%29.aspx) class which is part of GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

To convert images from scripts, you can use the [WIA Automation Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en). It's not strictly "native" library, but it's redistributable (refer to EULA).

Blow is a JScript example that shows how to convert an image to BMP. The original image can be PNG, GIF, JPEG or TIFF. Before running the script, register the *wiaaut.dll* library in the system.

```
var wiaIDUnknown = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}";
var wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";

// Load the original image
var img = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageFile");
img.LoadFile("D:\\MyFolder\\MyImage.gif");

switch (img.FormatID)
{
  case wiaIDUnknown:
    // Unknown image format or an invalid image file
    break;

  case wiaFormatBMP:
    // The image is already BMP
    break;

  default:
    // Specify the new format
    var ip  = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageProcess");
    ip.Filters.Add(ip.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID);
    ip.Filters(1).Properties("FormatID").Value = wiaFormatBMP

    // Convert and save the image
    img = ip.Apply(img);
    img.SaveFile("D:\\MyFolder\\MyImage.bmp");
}
```

See also [WIA documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630827.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I think from Windows 7 WIA DLL are provided with Windows.
Otherwise you can [download WIA](http://vbnet.mvps.org/files/updates/wiaautsdk.zip)

This is @Helen code converted to vbscript:

```
Const wiaIDUnknown = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
Const wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

Sub die(msg)
    WScript.Echo(msg)
    WScript.Quit(1)
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' MAIN

Set args = WScript.Arguments
If args.Count <> 2 Then die "Usage: WIA_convert.vbs <filename_input> <filename_output>"

filename_in = args.Item(0)
filename_out    = args.Item(1)

Set img_in = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
img_in.LoadFile filename_in
Wscript.Echo "Width  = " & img_in.Width
Wscript.Echo "Height = " & img_in.Height

Select Case img_in.FormatID
Case wiaIDUnknown
    Wscript.Echo "Unknown format"

Case wiaFormatBMP
    Wscript.Echo "Image is BMP"

Case Else
    Set ip  = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    ip.Filters.Add(ip.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID)
    ip.Filters(1).Properties("FormatID").Value = wiaFormatBMP

    Set img_out = ip.Apply(img_in)
    img_out.SaveFile(filename_out)
End Select
```